# wpf window is not activated

Tags: c#, wpf

I am launching a wpf application from a process. I am activating the main window on the event handler OnContentRendered. It is not getting activated. It returns false.

I am launching the application from a foreground process only. So it should be succeeded.

I set window.Topmost = true which works well. But Activate() returns false.

Window is on the topmost but not activated.

(Previously I asked one question without a clarification of actual problem. so I removed it)

Comment: I'm seeing a very similar issue, probably because my main window opens another window (for login) before I call Show(); - have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

See the MSDN documentation for SetForegroundWindow, which lists the rules for bringing a window to the front.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx

As an aside, it's very unusual to be calling this from OnContentRendered

Comment: The process was started by the foreground process. It is on the list. And can you please tell me where Activate() is supposed to be called ?

Comment: Is the Window visible?

Comment: yeah.. on the topmost. but it does not active.